# Use of ParseRoles manage admin user roles among groups

Tags: android, parse-platform, user-roles

I am just a week into using Parse.com, and I am using it to write a simple Android application. I am looking for some advice on how to handle a particular many-to-many relationship involving user roles.

So my app basically consists of Users, and Groups. Now a User can belong to multiple Groups, and a Group can have multiple Users. This is a classic many-to-many problem which I believe I can implement by using what is described here:

https://www.parse.com/docs/android/guide#relations-many-to-many

However, I have one slight twist to this. Users may also be administrators in some groups that they belong, enabling them to carry out some additional functionality, while being plain vanilla users in other groups. I initially thought of using two different relations, one for "users" and one for "admins". But then I stumbled across the ParseRoles in defining roles and access.

However, I am confused as to whether it is possible to use ParseRoles to implement the situation where Users can be Admins in some groups but not others, because it seems to me that ParseRoles defines a 'global' role that would extend across the application. But I might be wrong.

Any help on this is much appreciated. Cheers!

Comment: Hi,  were you able to implement the second approach stated below? How have you done it?

Comment: HI John, I actually abandoned this and began working on something else...

Answer (score 3):

There are two ways to go:

(1) Use the parse `__Role` class and define an admin `__Role` for each group.  You would create a generic admin `__Role`, and as groups are created (and destroyed), add (and remove) child roles to the generic role by changing it's `roles` relation.  (e.g. when creating GroupA, create and save a child of your generic admin role called GroupAAdmin).

You'd then give each Group object an ACL that specifies permissions for members of that group's admin role.  Probably primarily the ability to write that group object.

(2) Idea (1) means you need to get pretty good at manipulating roles and ACLs, setting up a role who can administer the roles, `afterSave` hooks and so on... several challenges therein, if you haven't done these things before.

More simply, but less secure and less functional, you could give each group another property called admin, which is a pointer to `__User`.  Then give your app the responsibility to check, prior to taking any action to modify the group, whether the current user is equal to the group's admin user.

Comment: I agree - the first approach is much more complex considering I am just looking to prototype this for now amongst family and friends. I'll probably try the second approach and let you know if I have any issues. Thanks!